Is sum of two nonnegative, continuous, quasiconvex functions on the same domain, quasiconvex?
In general the sum if two quasiconvex functions is not quasiconvex, for example, $x^3+x^2$. But is sum of two nonnegative, continuous, quasiconvex functions on the same domain, quasiconvex ? Seems like it should not be difficult to prove or find a counter example but I still haven't managed to do it.

Take something like $(x^3+10^6)+(x^2+10^6)$ on $[-999,\infty)$.

@SassatelliGiulio why is this not quasiconvex ?

Definitely not for the same reason yours is.

$$
f(x) = \sqrt{|x+1|} + \sqrt{|x-1|}
$$
is the sum of two nonnegative, continuous, quasiconvex functions on $\Bbb R$, but $f$ is not quasi convex:
$$
 f(0) = 2 > \sqrt 2 = \max \{ f(-1), f(1) \} \, .
$$
The following plot shows $\sqrt{|x+1|}$ (red), $\sqrt{|x-1|}$ (blue), and the sum (green).


Thank you @Martin R
